# Mapping fhir bundle resource to cda in javascript

Tags: javascript, hl7-fhir, dstu2-fhir, cda, hl7-cda

I have been trying to find a way to map fhir bundle resource to cda documents in javascript. I found some resource like "https://github.com/amida-tech/fhir2ccda" but it has no description.
Found $document fhir operation but it has no proper example.
Can anyone tell any resource related to it?

Answer (score 0):

You might look at https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179273-CCDA-.2F.20FHIR.20mapping.20stream.  That's probably the best place for discussion.

Comment: Useful link @lloyd

Answer (score 0):

For me the best option is to implement an xslt (this is what I implemented). 
So you should:

1. First you must have your resource in XML. If your input is application+fhir/xml go foward, if it is JSON you can transform to XML using HAPI FHIR, or other JSON 2 XML library.
2. Implement the XSLT
3. Apply de XSLT

Hope useful.

Comment: From where will I get xslt? I have bundle resource through search operation @marti

Comment: I'll have to implement it , as far as I know there is not official one. It would look something similar like:
    <xsl:template match="fhir:Bundle">
        <!-- Root CDA element -->
        <xsl:element name="ClinicalDocument" namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3">
            <!-- Real code universal -->
            <xsl:element name="realmCode" namespace="urn:hl7-org:v3">
                <xsl:attribute name="code">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'UV'"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>